# Url Launcher for flutter

Tags: python, flutter, dart, webview

I need to make a flutter app that has a button which has the function that when it is clicked, it will open http://10.0.2.2:5000 or the local host in a browser.

i have been using url launcher and watched youtube videos, but i cant seem to make it work. i've already did instructions from tutorials point with webview

here is my code

[image]

and i am getting this error
[image]

Comment: Specifically, what type of error are you getting? Or is your function just doing nothing?

Comment: I edited my post sir and thats the error i am getting

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open the url in a chrome browser, i.e. outside of your application web view.

You should try using the url launcher as such :-

```
    if (await canLaunchUrl(<your uri>)) {
      await launchUrl(<your uri>, mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication);
    }
```

What this will do is launch the url in a external chrome browser and not in the web view of the application.
Hope this helps!

Comment: can you take a look at my code sir, i already edited my post and thats the eror i am getting